# MS office downloaded and installed for free (from softonic), but now asking for product key?

Tags: microsoft-office, product-key

I searched for 'MS office download and installed for free' and found a link in Softonic website where I could do it successfully. However, now to use it, it is asking for product key.

How can I supply the product key? I don't have it. I wonder then how I could even download the whole software?

Comment: Office isn't freeware. What you downloaded is likely just a trial version.

Comment: And even if it was the full installation disc (Which type? Retail, OEM, VLP?), it is only that. It is not a key, let alone a genuine license.

Comment: You won't be able to install Office without a license.

Comment: @Ramhound: You mean "without a key", right? :-) You won't be eligible without a license!

Comment: I mean exactly what I said, which was very specific, you need a license to Office in order to use it.

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft Office is not free (except Office Starter, if it came preinstalled). You need a key to run it after the 30 day trial period.

The only way to get Office for free otherwise is with means that tend to be illegal in most countries. I do not recommend using those ways, and I do suggest purchasing it. If you download it from Microsoft directly, you know you won't get any spyware/adware/viruses with it, and you will have support as well.

If you need a free Office suite, I'd suggest trying [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) or [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/)

Answer (score 5):

The download and the installation were both free. *Using* the software will cost you money.

You can purchase a licence at http://office.microsoft.com/